# Prevent paper-dialogs from closing on affirmatitive button

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, paper-elements

I have a paper-dialog to submit a form, and on submit, any errors will be received from the server. If there are erorrs, they will be displayed in the dialog. I would like to handle the click event, and if there are no errors, close the dialog

```
<paper-dialog id="addSecretModal" heading="Add secret" transition="paper-dialog-transition-center">
     <paper-input id="dirInput" floatinglabel label="Directory" layout vertical class></paper-input>
     <paper-input id="secretInput" floatinglabel label="Directory" layout vertical class></paper-input>
    <paper-button dismissive>Cancel</paper-button>
    <paper-button id="confirmAddSecret" affirmative autofocus>Accept</paper-button>
</paper-dialog>
```

I've tried to remove affirmative, but this messes up the styling due to the way that Polymer handles dialogs. The affirmative button doesn't end up in the correct place, but rather above the dismissive button. I read that closeSelector="" would fix it, but to no avail. Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, and I feel like a bit of an idiot for doing this wrong this whole time. I was putting `closeSelector=""` in the paper-button tag, rather than in the paper-dialog tag. I also figured out how to make it so dismissive would still work, by doing `closeSelector="[dismissive]"`

```
<paper-dialog id="addSecretModal" heading="Add secret" transition="paper-dialog-transition-center" closeSelector="[dismissive]">
     <paper-input id="dirInput" floatinglabel label="Directory" layout vertical class></paper-input>
     <paper-input id="secretInput" floatinglabel label="Directory" layout vertical class></paper-input>
    <paper-button dismissive>Cancel</paper-button>
    <paper-button id="confirmAddSecret" affirmative autofocus>Accept</paper-button>
</paper-dialog>
```